# Improvement of PSTricks code for drawing of balls in a triangular box

Tags: pstricks, code-review

Consider the following.

**Code**

```
% lualatex filename.tex

\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\def\maksimumB{\fpeval{2*(1+3^(1/2))*\radius} }
\def\maksimumH{\fpeval{(3+3^(1/2))*\radius} }
\def\Angle[#1]#2#3#4{\pstMarkAngle{#2}{#3}{#4}{#1$60^{\circ}$}}

\begin{document}

\def\radius{21.5 }
\psset{unit=0.07cm}
\begin{pspicture}(\maksimumB,\maksimumH)
 \pnodes{P}(0,0)%
           (\maksimumB,0)%
           (!\maksimumB 2 div \maksimumH)
 \pspolygon(P0)(P1)(P2)
 \pnodes{C}(!3 sqrt \radius mul \radius)%
           (!2 3 sqrt add \radius mul \radius)%
           (!\maksimumB 2 div 1 3 sqrt add \radius mul)
 \pscircle(C0){\radius}
 \pscircle(C1){\radius}
 \pscircle(C2){\radius}
 \multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=1+1,\r=210+120}{3}{%
   \psdot(C\iA)
   \uput[\r](C\iA){$C_{\iB}$}
 }
\psset{%
  linestyle=dotted,%
  dotsep=1.5pt,%
  LabelSep=9,%
  MarkAngleRadius=5%
}
 \Angle[\footnotesize]{P2}{P1}{P0}
 \Angle[\footnotesize]{P1}{P0}{P2}
 \Angle[\footnotesize]{P0}{P2}{P1}
\psset{%
  LabelSep=7,%
  MarkAngleRadius=3%
}
 \pspolygon(C0)(C1)(C2)
 \Angle[\scriptsize]{C1}{C0}{C2}
 \Angle[\scriptsize]{C0}{C2}{C1}
 \Angle[\scriptsize]{C2}{C1}{C0}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Question**

I have the desired output but the code is somewhat messy, I think; can anyone help me simplify if?

Comment: My opinion: I'm not entirely sure how helpful this question would be to a wider audience (including many of the others posed this way). Voting to close as TL.

Comment: @Werner Why haven't you voted for the others then? It seems a bit strange to close this question if the others were not closed, but okay.

Comment: (1) I may have been too late to the game for the others; (2) The others may have had major improvements to the code which I feel this one doesn't; (3) Your questions states that "you think" the code is somewhat messy" which it doesn't seem to me. Again, it's just my opinion. Others can vote to leave it open...

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Please explain/list what _kind of improvements in PSTricks_ code, make it reachable to a _wider audience_ for eg: non-pstricks users. ? I tried following your previous questions with the same pattern but miserably failed due to my ignorance in PSTricks and less informative nature. My opnion: It should be OP<--> multi users information transfer not only OP <--> Q answerers

Comment: To all: Just close the question. This is exactly the same that goes on all the time for people like me when someone posts TikZ code. I'm not going to keep arguing my case; over and out.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I have no rep to close your Q, I just made a kind suggestion. Don't despair I like your enthusiasm with PSTricks. Good luck, you can always vote to reopen as well. we are working as community not individuals.

Comment: I don't despair, I just can't follow the arguments for closing it.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I just don't think the code can be improved that much. Herbert might have some magic to reveal a three-line masterpiece... who knows!? Two lines being taken up by the opening and closing of the `pspicture` environment. :)

Comment: You've asked at least a dozen of these, all with the same boilerplate commentary.  At some point, people will start to doubt the sincerity of the questions (i.e do you want to learn how to improve the code yourself, or do you just want someone else to do it for you).  It looks like you're getting close to that point.  I'm not expressing an opinion one way or the other, just rationalizing the close votes if you're confused by them.

Comment: No need for name calling, you mentioned that you didn't understand the close votes (none of which were me) so I gave my take on it.  I'm not sure what you find ignorant about that.

Comment: Maybe I phrased my comment poorly, I'm sorry if it offended you.

Comment: @ScottH. You are saying that I don't want to learn PSTricks and just want Herbert to do my work for me. If that is not ignorance, I don't know what is. I'm not continuing this conversation with you from now on.

Comment: I think @ScottH.'s concern is about the _same boilerplate commentary_: I have some code, it's messy and I want to improve it. I also have wondered about this.

Comment: I think we can create a new tag named `code-review` for this kind of question. `best-practice` and `code-review` tags should be appropriate for this question. If it is not possible in TeX.SeX then the last resort is [CodeReview.SeX](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bugbusters Idea is not bad, may be place it at meta.tex.sx for community discussion and consensus of tags.

Comment: Svend:  I didn't say that's what you _were_ doing, only that at some point it will start to _appear_ that way.  I tried to make that clear in the comment.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: To add to this discussion I've posted a question on Meta: [Tagging “Please improve my code” posts](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3541/5764). Also, a question that was just posted here has a similar flavour to yours. However, in my opinion it has a reach to a wider audience, since it references styles for chapter pages: [Code improvement and suggestions in template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113128/5764). Users can take the code and update it to their liking. Your post is particular to a triangle with 3 balls in it and doesn't scale to something larger/more abstract.

Comment: Hi Downvoter, This flavour question/s are in discussion at meta. It would be wise to leave a comment and  follow the meta links by @Werner and express your criticism/opinion if any and rethink on downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

marking the angles is the same. Putting the origin in the middle of the base also simplifies the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5mm}
\def\radius{21.5 }
\newlength\Radius \Radius=\radius\psunit
\begin{pspicture}(-3\Radius,0)(3\Radius,5\Radius)
\pstVerb{
  /maxB 2 dup 3 sqrt mul add \radius mul 2 div def
  /maxH 3 dup sqrt add \radius mul def }
\pnodes{P}(!maxB neg 0)(!maxB 0)(!0 maxH)
\pspolygon(P0)(P1)(P2)
\pnodes{C}(!\radius neg \radius)(\radius,\radius)(!0 1 3 sqrt add \radius mul)
\pscircle(C0){\Radius}\pscircle(C1){\Radius}\pscircle(C2){\Radius}
\pspolygon[showpoints,linestyle=dotted](C0)(C1)(C2)
\uput[225](C0){C1}\uput[-45](C1){C2}\uput[90](C2){C3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

with the current `pstricks.tex` you can also calculate coordinates as `P(+{algebraic},{algebraic})`. The `+` is the identifier for the special handling:

```
\psset{unit=0.5mm}
\def\radius{21.5 }
\newlength\Radius \Radius=\radius\psunit
\begin{pspicture}(-3\Radius,0)(3\Radius,5\Radius)
\pnodes{P}(+{-(1+sqrt(3))*\radius},0)(+{(1+sqrt(3))*\radius},0)%
  (+{0},{(3+sqrt(3))*\radius})
\pspolygon(P0)(P1)(P2)
\pnodes{C}(!\radius neg \radius)(\radius,\radius)(!0 1 3 sqrt add \radius mul)
\pscircle(C0){\Radius}\pscircle(C1){\Radius}\pscircle(C2){\Radius}
\pspolygon[showpoints,linestyle=dotted](C0)(C1)(C2)
\uput[225](C0){C1}\uput[-45](C1){C2}\uput[90](C2){C3}
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: code does not work with `pdflatex`. Normally `auto-pst-pdf` by [pdf] option works right ? I know it works with xelatex and latex->dvips->ps2pdf

Comment: put the `\pstVerb` into the `pspicture` environment. I'll change my code, see above.

Answer (score 7):

Without TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=6pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{fp}
\FPset\RR{2}% circle radius

\FPeval\XX{RR*root(2,3)}
\FPeval\RX{XX+RR}
\FPeval\Width{2*RX}
\FPeval\Height{RX*root(2,3)}

\def\Atom#1{%
    \pscircle(\XX,\RR){\RR}
    \psline(\RX;60)(0,0)(\RX,0)
    \bgroup
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}
    \psarc(0,0){15pt}{0}{60}
    \rput{*0}(25pt;30){$60^\circ$}
    \rput(\XX,\RR){%    
        \psline(\RR;60)(0,0)(\RR,0)
        \psarc(0,0){15pt}{0}{60}
        \qdisk(0,0){3pt}
        \rput{*0}(12pt;-150){$C_#1$}
        \rput{*0}(25pt;30){$60^\circ$}}
    \egroup
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Width,\Height)
    \Atom{1}
    \rput{120}(\Width,0){\Atom{2}}
    \rput{-120}(\RX,\Height){\Atom{3}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### How it works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt\relax

\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{fp}
\FPset\RR{2}% circle radius

\FPeval\XX{RR*root(2,3)}
\FPeval\RX{XX+RR}
\FPeval\Width{2*RX}
\FPeval\Height{RX*root(2,3)}

\def\Atom#1{%
    \pscircle(\XX,\RR){\RR}\pause
    \psline(\RX;60)(0,0)(\RX,0)\pause
    \bgroup
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}
    \psarc(0,0){15pt}{0}{60}
    \rput{*0}(25pt;30){$60^\circ$}\pause
    \rput(\XX,\RR){%    
        \psline(\RR;60)(0,0)(\RR,0)\pause
        \psarc(0,0){15pt}{0}{60}\pause
        \qdisk(0,0){3pt}
        \rput{*0}(12pt;-150){$C_#1$}
        \rput{*0}(25pt;30){$60^\circ$}\pause}
    \egroup
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}(\Width,\Height)
    \Atom{1}
    \rput{120}(\Width,0){\Atom{2}}
    \rput{-120}(\RX,\Height){\Atom{3}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The 19th frame is identical to the 18th one. But I am too lazy to remove the 19th one. :-)

Comment: This is a really elegant solution! I'll use this one instead of Herbert's, I think.

Comment: Hmm. It is as if the circles are not touching each other; there seems to be a tiny gab, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: You can change the `dimen` from `outer` (default) to `middle` for `\pscircle`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun with TikZ and the `angles` library from the CVS version.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=7cm, y=7cm, thick, line join=round,
  dots/.style={dash pattern=on 1\pgflinewidth off 2\pgflinewidth},
  dot/.style={circle,fill,draw,inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2pt}]
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{.5/(1+1/tan 30)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\vB{2*\r}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (n-0) -- ++ (0:1) coordinate (n-1)
                             -- ++ (120:1) coordinate (n-2) -- cycle;
\foreach \a/\b/\c[count=\cnt from 0] in {1/\vB/\vB, \vB/1/\vB, \vB/\vB/1}
  \draw (barycentric cs:n-0=\a,n-1=\b,n-2=\c) node[dot] (C-\cnt) {}
        node[anchor=30+120*\cnt] {$C_{\pgfmathprint{int(\cnt+1)}}$} circle [radius=\r];
\draw[dots] (C-0) -- (C-1) -- (C-2) -- (C-0);
\foreach \cnt[evaluate={\pCnt=int(Mod(\cnt-1,3)); \nCnt=int(Mod(\cnt+1,3));}] in {0,...,2}
  \path[nodes={draw, dots, angle radius=+10pt, angle eccentricity=1.8,
               pic text=$\scriptstyle60^\circ$, pic text options={draw=none}}]
   pic {angle=C-\nCnt--C-\cnt--C-\pCnt} pic {angle=n-\nCnt--n-\cnt--n-\pCnt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With tkz-euclide and no calculation (compass and ruler)

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}     
 \definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}   
 \tkzSetUpColors[background=fondpaille,text=Maroon]  

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(8,0){B}
  \tkzDefEquilateral(A,B)\tkzGetPoint{C}
   %first circle
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection= onto A--B](C)  \tkzGetPoint{Hc}
  \tkzDefLine[bisector](B,A,C) \tkzGetPoint{a}
  \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,Hc,C) \tkzGetPoint{hc}
  \tkzInterLL(A,a)(Hc,hc) \tkzGetPoint{Oa}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection= onto A--B](Oa)  \tkzGetPoint{I}
   %second circle
  \tkzDefLine[bisector](C,B,A) \tkzGetPoint{b}
  \tkzDefLine[bisector](B,Hc,C) \tkzGetPoint{ha}
  \tkzInterLL(B,b)(Hc,ha) \tkzGetPoint{Ob}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection= onto A--B](Ob)  \tkzGetPoint{J} 
   %third circle
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection= onto A--C](B)  \tkzGetPoint{Hb}
  \tkzDefLine[bisector](C,Hb,B) \tkzGetPoint{hb}
  \tkzInterLL(C,Hc)(Hb,hb) \tkzGetPoint{Oc}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection= onto C--B](Oc)  \tkzGetPoint{K}
   %drawing
  \tkzDefMidPoint(C,B) \tkzGetPoint{E}  
  \tkzDrawPolygon[color=Maroon](A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawPolygon[color=Maroon,dashed](Oa,Ob,Oc)
  \tkzDrawCircle(Oa,I)    
  \tkzDrawCircle(Ob,J)   
  \tkzDrawCircle(Oc,K)
  \tkzDrawPoints(Oa,Ob,Oc,A,B,C)
   %labels
  \tkzLabelPoints[left](Oa,A)
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](Ob,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](Oc,C)  \end{tikzpicture}                                                                   
 \end{document}
```

[image]